Module not found error when trying to import '@vercel/analytics/react' in App.js in React app
Upon npm start, I am running into this error:
Module not found: Can't resolve '@vercel/analytics/react' in 'C:\path-to-react-app\trivia-app\src'
Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
As per instructions in https://vercel.com/docs/analytics/quickstart, I ran npm i @vercel/analytics and added import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react"; in my App.js file.
I have tried all of this so far:

delete package-lock.json and rerun npm install.
tried import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics"; instead

These are the packages in my package-lock.json:
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "trivia-app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@vercel/analytics": "^1.2.2",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
        "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      }
    },

This is how my App.js is organised:
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import WelcomePage from './components/WelcomePage';
import QuizPage from './components/QuizPage';
import ResultsPage from './components/ResultsPage';
import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react";

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<WelcomePage />} />
          <Route path="/quiz" element={<QuizPage />} />
          <Route path='/results' element={<ResultsPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Analytics />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


Have you tried deleting both package-lock.json and ./node_modules before reinstalling your dependencies?

I am a bit confused on that front: when i did create-react-app, node_modules was not created for me. and on my subsequent npm installs, it did not get installed as well.

Are you getting any errors when you run npm i? Or do you see that the install successfully completes? Also I would update your question to include your package.json  instead of the snippet from package-lock.json.

i managed to make it work by force installing node_modules! not sure why it wasnt there in the first place, myabe i deleted it by accident at some point and it refused to download

I am not sure about the missing ./node_modules and I am not familiar with Vercel to know if that is a normal setup, but your package.json does not look correct.
You have defined a packages object within it, which does not appear to be an official npm property and I am not familiar with it.
With that said, you could try creating a new package.json file that is saved at the path: C:\path-to-react-app\trivia-app\package.json.
And within that file, copy the original packages object for "trivia-app" to the new package.json. So the new package.json file would look like this:
{
  "name": "trivia-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@vercel/analytics": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
}

And then try running npm i from within your trivia-app directory (or using whatever Vercel specific commands you maybe using).

the section I included in the original question belongs to my package-lock.json, my package.json looks similar to what you have outlined. that does not seem to be the problem

The problem I encountered was that the package did not show up in package.json file after running npm i @vercel/analytics
This is how i resolved this issue in nextjs v14.1.0
Manually Add the Package to package.json:
1. Head to the Vercel Analytics Package Page:
Visit the Vercel Analytics package page on npm.
2. Grab the Package Version:
Note down the latest version of the package available on the npm page.

Add this in package.json file
"dependencies": {
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"@vercel/analytics": "1.3.1" // Make sure to mention the latest version for this package

}


4. Install the dependencies
npm i or yarn

